# Could not find a storyboard named 'Dialog' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

現在ボタンが押されるとカスタムダイアログを表示させるといったプログラムを組んでいるのですが、`Storyboard`の`identify`の`Storyboard ID`に「Dialog」と入力して以下のコードを実行してみたところ、`Could not find a storyboard named 'Dialog' in bundle NSBundle`というエラーが発生して別の`ViewController`を表示することができません。上記に書いた設定の他に何か行わなければならない設定があるのでしょうか？原因が分からず困っています。どなたか分かる方にご教授いただきたいです。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Dialog" bundle:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

指定するのは「Storyboard ID」じゃなくて、**Storyboardのファイル名**です。プロジェクトを作成して、変更してなければ、「**Main**」となってるはず。

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
}
```

なんとなく、Storyboardではなくて、Storyboard内のあるインスタンス（おそらくはView Controller？）を指定なさりたいような印象を受けますが、もしそうなら、質問内容を編集して、紛れがないような表現にしてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り"Main"とするとエラーが出なくなりました。また、やりたいこととしてはViewControllerを指定したいので、質問を変更したいと思います。ありがとうございます。